# Using four level If Else syntax and percentage

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got some stuck here with my jobs here I got some test like this:

Illustration : 
There are 4 edges which have their own tax rate:

- From Rp 0 to Rp 50,000,000 the tax rate is 5%.
- From Rp 50,000,000 to    Rp 250,000,000 the tax rate is 15%.
- From Rp 250,000,000 to Rp    500,000,000 the tax rate is 25%.
- Above 500,000,000 the tax rate is    30%.

and heres my Code :

```
<?php
$a = //Input for Variable

    $b = 5*$a/100  ; 
    $c = 15*$a/100  ; 
    $d = 25*$a/100  ; 
    $e = 30*$a/100  ;

if($a ==  o and =< 50000000){   
    echo $b ;
} 
elseif($a => 50000000 and =< 250000000){
    echo $c ;
}
elseif($a => 250000000 and =<500000000){
    echo $d ;
}
else{
    echo $e ;
}
?>
```

But I got some error when after I fill Value for Variable $a.

Comment: You need to have the `$a` in the `and` part as well - `($a => 50000000 and $a=< 250000000)`

Comment: Also should `($a ==  o` be `($a ==  0` with a zero.

Comment: i got this error "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)"

Comment: Replace `=>` with `>=` and `=<` with `<=`

Comment: Sorry - correction to my earlier correction `($a == o` should be `($a >= 0` as check it was == 0 and <= 50000000 wasn't good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few minor changes that you've to do
- Missing variable in each `if` condition
- Instead of `o` take `0`
- Always put the `=` sign last like `>=` or `<=` or `!=`
- Extra :- Optimize the code for better performance (take less variable)

```
<?php
    $a = 50000000;
    if($a ==  0 and $a <= 50000000)
        $total = 5*$a/100;
    else if($a >= 50000000 and $a <= 250000000)
        $total = 15*$a/100;
    else if($a >= 250000000 and $a <= 500000000)
        $total = 25*$a/100;
    else
        $total = 30*$a/100;
    echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it work well, thanks for advise I'll keep in mind

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
$a = //Input for Variable

$b = 5*$a/100  ; 
$c = 15*$a/100  ; 
$d = 25*$a/100  ; 
$e = 30*$a/100  ;

if($a ==  0 && $a <= 50000000){   
   echo $b ;
} elseif($a == "Sun"){
   echo "Have a nice Sunday!";
} 
elseif($a >= 50000000 && $a <= 250000000){
   echo $c ;
}
elseif($a >= 250000000 && $a <= 500000000){
   echo $d ;
}
else{
  echo $e ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works ; so it should using "&&" instead "And" yaa ?